# Powershell hash containskey returns false incorrectly

Tags: powershell, hash

I have a Powershell script which gets a list of Remote Desktop user sessions and puts them into a hash by SessionID.

```
# Create a hashtable which contains all of the remote desktop sessions by SessionId
$userSessionBySessionID = @{}
ForEach($userSession in Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName $collectionName)
{
    $userSessionBySessionID.Add($userSession.SessionId, $userSession)
}
```

I then can then dump the $userSessionByID in the PowerShell ISE

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession                                                                                                                                                       
8                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession                                                                                                                                                       
7                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession                                                                                                                                                       
6                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession                                                                                                                                                       
5                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession                                                                                                                                                       
4                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession                                                                                                                                                       
2                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession                                                                                                                                                       
1                              Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDUserSession
```

The frustrating part is that $userSessionBySessionID.ContainsKey(4) returns false. What am I missing here? I've tried $userSessionBySessionID.ContainsKey("4") as well, but that also returns false.

Comment: What type is the sessionid? What does `$userSession.SessionId.Gettype()` return?

Comment: I think the issue may be that $userSession.SessionId.GetType() returns UInt32, while Get-Process returns an object where SessionId is an Int32.

Comment: Does that mean `$userSessionBySessionID.ContainsKey(4 -as [uint32])` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the issue may be that `$userSession.SessionId.GetType()` returns `[UInt32]`

In testing that is your issue exactly. Consider the following test where I create a hashtable using `[UInt32]`.

```
$test = @{}
1..10 | %{$test.add($_ -as [uint32],$_%2)}
```

Running `$test.containskey(6)` returns false as you have seen. I also get the same issue with `$test.containskey("6")`. However this returns true....

```
$test.containskey(6 -as [uint32])
```

**Note:** You don't need to use the `-as` operator here as you can just do a simple cast with `[uint32]6` however if you are using variables that contain integers `-as` would be helpful.

The key itself can be near any object and `containskey()` is returning the correct result in all cases. Your hashtable does not have a key with the *integer* 6. Furthermore, [`[uint32]` cannot be converted to `[int]` since it has a higher upper bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307271/what-is-the-difference-between-int32-and-uint32) so a cast would not be possible. This would be a reason why PowerShell or the underlying .Net would not be doing an "automatic" cast. In practice I don't think this ever happens in this scenario.

Point is be sure you are type aware.

Same example as above except this time we are using integers.

```
1..10 | %{$test.add($_,$_%2)}

$test.containskey(6)
True

$test.containskey("6")
False
```

I can reverse the findings when I create the keys with strings.

```
1..10 | %{$test.add("$_",$_%2)}

$test.containskey(6)
False

$test.containskey("6")
True
```

Comment: That was the issue. You have to be very careful when using Powershell hashes when keying off a field of an object. Everything should always be cast to a single type when referencing a key.

Comment: @bpeikes Just want to be sure you caught an edit I just made. You dont _need_ to use `-as` and you can just do `[uint32]6`. I only showed it expecting that you might be using variables instead of magic numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out how to get it to work. I always cast the fields when adding the hash and when trying to get values out, or testing for existence. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and found that $userSessionBySessionID.ContainsKey(4) will return false. But $userSessionBySessionID.ContainsKey("4") returns true.

The code I used is as follows. Please give it a try and let me know if it helps:

```
    # Create a hashtable which contains all of the remote desktop sessions by SessionId
    $userSessionBySessionID = @{}

    Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName $collectionName | % {$userSessionBySessionID.Add($_.SessionId.ToString().Trim(), $_)}
```

**More Technical Info:**

The definition of the Contains Key as per internal help is:

`bool ContainsKey(System.Object key)`

You can parse string to this but not an integer.
You can also check the above definition by running the below code i.e. without the parenthesis. It displays definition for the method and any overload.:

`$userSessionBySessionID.ContainsKey`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the responses from others, I figure out what the issue is, namely SessionId is a different type when coming from Get-RDUserSession and Get-Process. The code was changed to:

```
# Create a hashtable which contains all of the remote desktop sessions by SessionId
$userSessionBySessionID = @{}
ForEach($userSession in Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName $collectionName)
{
    $userSessionBySessionID.Add([long]$userSession.SessionId, $userSession)
}

$userSessionsRunningSurveyor = @()
ForEach($proc in Get-Process -IncludeUserName)
{
    $sessionId = [long]$proc.SessionId
    $execPath = $proc.Path
    Write-Debug "Checking for SessionID $sessionId, Path $execPath"
    if($userSessionBySessionID.ContainsKey($sessionId) -and $execPath -and $collectionPaths.ContainsKey($execPath))
    {
        $userName=$proc.UserName
        Write-Debug "Found user $userName running $execPath on SessionID $sessionId"
        $userSession = $userSessionBySessionID[$sessionId]
        $userSessionsRunningSurveyor += $userSession
    }
}
```

Note the cast to [long] when adding a key and when checking for existence of a key.